# C++ data block management

Tags: c++

(Having trouble coming up with a good question title here!)

In the last few months, I seem to keep writing code for doing the same task (in minor variations). So I'm wondering if there's anything in the C++ standard libraries (or maybe Boost) that can help. Let me try to explain what I'm trying to do…

As a concrete example, suppose I have a logical file that's made up of several physical files on disk. What I want to do is write a function like

```
void ReadData(void * buffer, UInt64 offset, UInt64 size);
```

Seems simple enough, right? However, it's actually quite fiddly:

- First, I need to figure out which physical file contains the requested logical offset.
- Next, I need to check whether the requested `size` spans a physical file boundary.
- Actually, in the worst case, it's plausible the `size` could span *multiple files*, although that's unlikely.
- Finally, I need to `fread()` the right blocks of data, from the right files, into the right offsets in `buffer`.
- Checking that neither `offset` nor `size` exceeds the available data would be prudent as well.

None of this is astonishingly *hard*, it's just fiddly and easy to screw up. There are endless opportunities for off-by-one bugs, out-of-bounds accesses and so forth. It's also really awkward to test thoroughly. In short, this isn't the sort of code you want to end up writing multiple times over.

Does anybody know of anything in the libraries that will help me here? I'm mostly interested in something for handling all the coordinate transformations, not the actual I/O operations themselves.

Comment: B+-trees, and B+-tree index files?